# AWS cognito integrate with AppAuth

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, appauth

I need to do an authorization workflow on a Cognito user pool for a mobile app with self-hosted login/signUp screen.

I have tested the login/sign up to Cognito user pool with a native UI screen, but I need it to work with the self-hosted Cognito screen.

I would like to use AppAuth on the mobile side for handling the process.

No examples or sample code found yet. Please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: Are you developing a Native mobile app or Hybrid (e.g ReactNative)?

Comment: hi @Ashan is a ReactNative, but this flow can be on native layer

Comment: Have tried using Amplify Library https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/aws-mobile-react-native.html by AWS.

Comment: @Ashan can I use amplify to interface with self-hosted UI for user pool? not federated? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AWS Cognito Auth` offers self-hosted Web UI for native sign-in. See the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-configuring-app-integration.html) for complete setup.

The Amazon Cognito Auth SDK for iOS and Android simplifies adding sign-up, sign-in functionality in your apps. With this SDK, you can use Cognito User Pools’ app integration and federation features, with a customizable UI hosted by AWS to sign up and sign in users, and with the built-in federation for external identity providers via SAML. To learn more see the [Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-federation-beta-release-overview.html).

You can now use Amazon Cognito Authto easily add sign-in and sign-out to your mobile apps. Your User Pool in Amazon Cognito is a fully managed user directory that can scale to hundreds of millions of users, so you don't have to worry about building, securing, and scaling a solution to handle user management and authentication.

**Sample apps:**

[Android demo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoAuthDemo)

[iOS demo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoAuth-Sample)

**The source code of the library:**

[Android](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/tree/master/aws-android-sdk-cognitoauth)

[iOS](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/tree/master/AWSCognitoAuth)